# Using dedicated GPU on kali rolling

Tags: kali-linux, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I'm trying to use dedicated GPU in my laptop Dell Precision 3510. 
I have integrated Intel HD Graphics 530 and dedicated AMD FirePro W5130M, which Kali sees as Radon HD 8830M.
I already tried to install AMDGPU-PRO and FGLRX on older systems. No luck.
I tried toy use Prime, but running anything with DRI_PRIME_1 hangs the laptop.
I found that Bumblebee works only with Intel.
I tried W5130Mto set AMD card as primary using prime, but i don't know how to do that.

If i run

> xrandr --listproviders

I get

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x6f cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 7 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

Is there anything i'm missing? Is it even possible to use dedicated AMD graphic card on linux?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i found a solution.
My dedicated GPU is automatically turn off with "DynOff" in switch file.
All i have to do is type "radeon.runpm=0" after "splash" in GRUB.
After that my dedicated GPU is turned on, and automatically used in games.